# pybind11 - Wrapping overloaded assignment operator?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm using pybind11 to expose C++ functions to a Python interface. I want to wrap the overloaded assignment operator but don't know how. The documentation and examples provided don't really cover it, at least from what I saw.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Num{
  public:
    Num(const double& num) : m_val(num), m_type(Num::Type::e_none){}

    Num& operator=(const double& rhs){m_val = rhs;}

  private:
    double m_val;
};
```

And here's the wrapping:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(demo, m){
    py::class_<Num>(m, "Num")
        .def(py::init<const double&>())
        // Overloaded assignment operator binding ?
        ;
}
```

My main concern is preserving Num's data type when assigning it to a float. e.g.:

```
>>> m = Num(4.5)
>>> type(m)
<class 'demo.Num'>
>>> m = 5.5
>>> type(m)
<class 'float'>
```

This is my first time working with C++ extensions and bindings so any insight on what I should do would be great!

Comment: Can't be done (okay, you could intercept the global dictionary `__setitem__`, but that's a terrible hack and very fragile). At issue is that Python uses reference assignment, so there is no assignment operator to override. To be specific: that second assignment drops the old reference to `Num` then reassigns to `5.5`. At no point is any method of `Num` involved. An alternative could be if all `Num` instances lived in some class or module, then you could override that module/class's `__setitem__`.

Comment: Ah, I see. So Python creates a brand new native bool object that the name "m" points to instead of the previously created Num object. I'm not interested in messing with any dunder functions atm, but this definitely helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.def("assign", &Num::operator=);
```

Please refer to https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/250 for more details.

Comment: This is work only with **Num& operator=(const Num& )** function definition, so cannot manage double affectation.

Comment: You could do this:  
`.def("assign", py::overload_cast<double>&Num::operator=); `.  
Provided you have an assignment operator that takes a double.  
or this:  
`.def("assign", [](double value, Num& self){self = Num(value)});`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to Voya's answer, but the syntax in plfoley's answer using "py::overload_cast" is incorrect. It should be `.def("assign", py::overload_cast<const double&>(&Num::operator=));`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33622868)